# Model converges when using orthogonal polynomials but fails to converge when using raw polynomials

Tags: mixed-model, correlation, convergence, polynomial, variance-inflation-factor

I am fitting linear mixed effect models with random slopes (lmer4 package), and I recently attempted to add a quadratic term due to some theory behind (the quadratic ends up also in the random slopes, see models below).
I now realized that fitting the model with **orthogonal polynomials** leads to a model that converges, while the model fitted with **raw polynomials** does not converge.
**Do you know the underlying reason for this difference?**

I am also **not sure if I should be using orthogonal polynomials or not in the first place**. In fact, my first and second order terms have a correlation of -0.69 (a bit high) but when investigating their Variance Inflation Factors there is no worrying signal of multicollinearity (1.0013).

So far my approach would be:

1. The correlation is borderline, but according to VIF it appears to be
   ok, so I keep the raw polynomials
2. I try to fit the model
3. The model does not converge, I remove the quadratic term
4. Re-fit the model -> the model converges

Nevertheless, I afraid that **by not using orthogonal polynomials** I miss an interesting result (supported by some literature). But I would first like to know why it converges in one case and it does in the other. Hope you can help me out :)

To get an idea, these are the 2 models:

1. output~ poly(abundance,2, raw=**T**) + climate + management + (1|study_ID) + (poly(abundance,2, raw=**T**|tree), data=data, REML=T) **(fails to converge)**
2. output~ poly(abundance,2, raw=**F**) + climate + management + (1|study_ID) + (poly(abundance,2, raw=**F**|tree), data=data, REML=T) **(converges)**

In total there are 649 data points

- **Climate** is a factor (2 levels)
- **Management** is a factor (2 levels)
- **Abundance** is of course continuous
- **Tree** is a factor and has 24 levels
- **study_ID** is a factor with 44 levels